# SUM() in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here I am trying to get the data as below `(EXPECTED)`.

```
ID | Project | SC   | PO   | INV
---+---------+------+------+-----
1  | test1   | NULL | 1    | NULL
2  | test2   | NULL | NULL | NULL
```

but as per my stored procedure I am getting the output as

```
ID | Project | SC   | PO | INV
---+---------+------+----+-----
1  | test1   | NULL | 1  | NULL
2  | test2   | NULL | 1  | NULL
```

Maybe the result from my inner query is displaying the PO recieved for `Project test1` as `PO test2` too. Which should not happen. Because Project 'test1' is present in both `BudgetDetails` and `Details` tables.

Any help guys to correct the sum() query i have written?

```
SELECT 
    BD.ID, BD.Project,
    (SELECT SUM(Amount) AS SC 
     FROM Details (NOLOCK) a 
     INNER JOIN BudgetDetails (NOLOCK) b ON a.Project = b.Project 
     WHERE ProcurementStatus = 'SC' AND a.Project = b.Project) AS SC,
    (SELECT SUM(Amount) as PO 
     FROM Details (NOLOCK) a 
     INNER JOIN BudgetDetails(NOLOCK) b ON a.Project = b.Project 
     WHERE ProcurementStatus = 'PO' AND a.Project = b.Project) AS PO,
    (SELECT SUM(Amount) as INV 
     FROM Details (NOLOCK) a 
     INNER JOIN BudgetDetails(NOLOCK) b ON a.Project = b.Project 
     WHERE ProcurementStatus = 'INV' AND a.Project = b.Project) AS INV
 FROM 
     BudgetDetails (NOLOCK) BD
 WHERE 
     BD.Quarter = @Quarter AND BD.Year = @Year
 GROUP BY 
     BD.ID, BD.Project
```

Comment: Can you provide the data too?

Comment: @Xedni  Input data will Quarter and year (1, 2016)

Comment: I mean what the data in the `BudgetDetails` and `Details` tables looks like. Your query has some oddities in it, but without knowing what your data and source tables look like, it's just guesswork.

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix your query, you will required `AND a.Project = BD.Project` in your sub-query

You are better to re-write it using CASE STATEMENT or PIVOT

```
 SELECT 
    BD.ID, BD.Project,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ProcurementStatus = 'SC' THEN Amount END) as SC,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ProcurementStatus = 'PO' THEN Amount END) as PO,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ProcurementStatus = 'INV' THEN Amount END) as INV,

 FROM   
        BudgetDetails (NOLOCK) BD
 LEFT JOIN 
        Details (NOLOCK) D  ON  BD.Project  = D.Project
 WHERE  
        BD.Quarter = @Quarter 
 AND    BD.Year = @Year
 GROUP BY 
        BD.ID, 
        BD.Project
```

EDIT 1:  change from INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN to reflect @beginner's requirement

Comment: I can't use Details table in my main query. As this prevents the NULL SC,PO,INV values from BudgetDetails table to be displayed

Comment: @beginner: I think you could use `left join` to show all rows in BudgetDetails  table